# Cannot resolve method ParseDouble

Tags: java, android

I'm working with java in Android Studio and trying to convert a string from a `TextView` into a double so it can be used to calculate some figures on a person's income.

The method `ParseDouble` will not allow me to run it in this way. I'm wondering why it will not compile. It simply says cannot resolve method. According to the documentation, it accepts a string as a parameter.

Here is my code currently:

```
package ericleeconklin.costoflivingcalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.lang.Object;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.Double;

public class EnterIncome extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_income);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_enter_income, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void getIncome(View income){
        View myIncomeString;
        myIncomeString = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.enterIncome);
        Double myIncome;
        myIncome = Double.ParseDouble(myIncomeString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean [`Double.parseDouble(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: Method names in Java are generally camelCase. PascalCase is generally reserved for class names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

myIncomeString is a TextView you have to get first the text ( which is EditText) and then get toString()

Change to be :

```
public void getIncome(View income){
        TextView myIncomeString;
        myIncomeString = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.enterIncome);
        Double myIncome;
        myIncome = Double.parseDouble(myIncomeString.getText().toString());
    }
```

Comment: myIncomeString is a TextView you have to get first the text ( which is EditText) and then get toString()

Comment: you should add your last comment to your answer. It is generally a good idea to explain your answer rather than to "just post code".

Comment: Durhh. Thanks. I was pretty dumb on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Method is [`Double.parseDouble(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) not `Double.ParseDouble(String)`.

Comment: That is only part of the problem.